# How to log SqlDataAdapter exceptions asynchronously?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, logging, sqldataadapter

I have ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using a SqlDataAdapter for handling sql server methods. The method below returns nothing when an exception occurs, so I don't have any information when there is an error with a sql server command.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string pSql, List<SqlParameter> prm)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pSql, sqlConnection);
        int result = 0;

        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }

        try
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prm.ToArray());

            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

How can I asynchronously log exceptions without disrupting the user experience?Additionally, I want to log it to database and if there is a timeout exception then logging this timeout can get timeout again when logging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SqlDataAdapter code in your sample. That being said, there are [three DataAdapter events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1wk41s(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use to respond to changes made to data at the data source.

**RowUpdating**,
**RowUpdated**, &
**FillError**

There is also a:

> **Status** property to determine if an error has occurred during the
>   operation and, if desired, to control the actions against the current
>   and resulting rows.

You can asynchronously log exceptions in those events when there is an error.

[Examples from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1wk41s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
protected static void OnRowUpdated(
  object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)
  {
    args.Row.RowError = args.Errors.Message;
    args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;

    Task.Run(() => LogError());
  }
}

protected static void FillError(object sender, FillErrorEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Errors.GetType() == typeof(System.OverflowException))
  {
    // Code to handle precision loss.
    //Add a row to table using the values from the first two columns.
    DataRow myRow = args.DataTable.Rows.Add(new object[]
       {args.Values[0], args.Values[1], DBNull.Value});
    //Set the RowError containing the value for the third column.
    args.RowError = 
       "OverflowException Encountered. Value from data source: " +
       args.Values[2];
    args.Continue = true;

    Task.Run(() => LogError());
  }
}

private void LogError()
{
    // logging code
}
```

Comment: thank you but i donw know how to log anysc. Thats what i am asking actually.

Comment: @doganhisa I've updated my answer. The simplest way is to create a Task.